# Logic Tree into Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to make a Breeding Roller for a Fakemon RPG I run.
I'm using Googsheets
[GOOGSHEET Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDqbg.png)

I'm new to coding in general. But I've done a bit of research. I'm 90% fairly certain that it CAN be done I just don't know which formula would work best.
This is what I've come up with.

=(cell) IF Empty Ignore (end)

=(cell) IF not Empty move to (cell)

- =RANDBETWEEN (1,10)
- =5> "TRUE" (trait is in child)
- =5< "FALSE" (trait is not in child)

I looked up

COUNTIF

DCOUNT

DCOUNTA

I'm GUESSING using the Database of the list of traits is what the formula would search for to check to see if the cell is EMPTY or NOTEMPTY?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated! TIA!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are going to achieve as you don't give info about cells you refer to. Please give an example of source data and result data you want to have.

Comment: Would you consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You might find the IFS formula useful. It allows you to specify many if conditions in sequence without having to write a crazy long formula